# My Google Chrome.app is too big. Can I remove previous versions from the Content folder?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I recently scanned my hard-drive looking for things that are taking up too much space. I couldn't believe what I found: The `Google Chrome.app` takes over 5 GB on my hard-drive (Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2). (Remember, I am not talking about the browser cache or RAM allocation, but simply the app itself.)

I looked inside the `.app` package and found a `Versions` folder containing Google Chrome versions dating back to 2013 (31.0).

1. Alright, so I have to manually delete old Google Chrome versions from inside the app? Why is Google Chrome not deleting old versions itself?

Doing this actually does reduce the `Contents` folder to about 190 MB, but the `.app` package does not shrink. (I am guessing it's a sort of zip archive that won't shrink automatically?)

2. Therefore, the problem I am facing now is that even though the contents of the Google Chrome app are of reasonable size again, the app package is still 5 GB large. Any idea how to shrink it?

Yes, I can simply re-install Google Chrome, but I would have to remember doing this every once in a while, which is a pain, I simply can't believe that there is not at least a Settings switch to `Clear app versions`. Maybe you have a better solution or have experienced this as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should, afaik, only keep the 2 last versions.

You can safely delete any older than the latest two - then keep an eye on it to make sure it doesn't happen again.

It's likely a glitch that has prevented it keeping up to date. It would be worth checking if it has all versions back to 31.0 or whether there is a time-gap, then just the last two.
If there is a gap, then there's the possibility that the glitch has cleared, but didn't auto-clean up versions from earlier.

An .app package, btw, is simply a folder - nothing more complex than that. Add .app to any folder & watch it change.
The size reported ought to change next time it's accessed, though at worst could take a reboot.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to refresh the size by calling `touch /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app`. I will monitor and see if this keeps happening (I was wondering if it may be a permission problem). For now it worked even when keeping only the latest version. Not sure how to check if a version was skipped, but it looked fairly continuous and incremental.

Comment: If it keeps doing it, then I guess it could be perms.  Wouldn't hurt to run a perms check over the drive, just in case. The 'continuity check' was really to in case it was clearly a bunch of leftovers from last year or whatever with a broken history then just 2 latest; which might indicate whatever had broken had also fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue today and my solution was simple: trash the app and download it again from the internet. You won't miss any data, bookmarks, extensions or whatever, because all those are stored inside the Library/Application Support folder. If you don't touch that folder, you should be safe.

Then just reinstall the new Chrome.app downloaded and keep surfing. Really easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well.

Google Chrome having 15GB of leftover version

and Google Chrome Canary 65GB

Not sure what is the solution for this to never happen again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).