# Chrome is 12.2 Gigs - removed about 20 versions and still the same. How to reduce the size?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, disk-space

I was shocked to see Chrome at 12 gigs on my hard drive and found it was keeping versions for some reason. I searched if i could remove these versions and found that i could.

In the [same thread](https://superuser.com/questions/899044/my-google-chrome-app-is-too-big-can-i-remove-previous-versions-from-the-content) the guy said he removed the verisons but the size didn't change. (That's exactly what happened to me. The size of the app is still 12 gigs.) Later in the thread he said he managed to refresh the size by

> calling touch /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app.

how do i call touch /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app ??? what is that?

Any other help on reducing the size of chrome would be really appreciated too.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that is an issue of old cached files that you no longer need; lets first check and see where all this data is.

Open a terminal

```
cd /Applications/Google\/ Chrome.app/Contents
du -hs *
```

Here, I can see ~500MB in Versions, I can then use `rm` to delete the old ones:

```
cd Versions
ls -alF
rm -r ./Versions/<old version numbers>
```

If you have a different directory that has all of the data, please share the output of `ls -alF /Applications/Google\/ Chrome.app/Contents`